# How do I change the clone URL for my GIT repositories?

Tags: git, repository, git-clone, git-config

I have moved my Git repository from one IP to a different IP. And now I am facing a problem with changing it's clone url.

Old URL: 1] http://105.15.96.261/something/some_repo.git

Now I have moved to a new IP & I want the clone url to be: 2] http://103.11.37.243:4040/something/some_repo.git

How do i achieve this? I am able to clone the repositories using second URl but it is not appearing in the new set up, it shows up the old URL.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `git remote set-url` command.